# Pyminizip prompting password only for the first time

Tags: python, password-protection

I am trying to password protect my zip file(with multiple txt files) using pyminizip.commpress_multiple

```
pyminizip.compress_multiple(["dummy.txt", "dummy1.txt"], [], "myzip.zip", "password", 9)
```

This is creating a password-protected zip file. When I try to extract the zip file for the first time it is prompting for the password.

From the second time onwards, it is not asking for the password.

Any ideas why this is happening ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What program or code are you using to extract passworded zip?

Comment: Usually many archive extracting programs remember last password of archive not to bother you asking password every time. It is not a problem - if you go to another computer it will ask for password again.

Comment: I am using Python to set the password to zip file

Comment: You showed us code of compressing function, can you also show code of extracting function that you use?

Comment: And manually trying to extract the files

Comment: What program or code are you using when manually extracting zip?

Comment: I am programmatically generating the zip file
and trying to extract the files by right-clicking on the file and selecting "Extract files" option.

Comment: I think there is no problem with ZIP and it is encrypted with password. The thing is when you do right click and extract then Windows usually remembers last password. Windows always remembers something for users not to bother them extra time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not asking password second time is because when you right-click on `"Extract files"` then Windows remembers password after you first entering it. So second time Windows automatically uses remembered password.

Windows always tries to remember different kind of information for use, not to bother user extra time.

In this case Windows remembers password only by full path of this zip file. You can try moving file to a different folder, or renaming file, or even renaming folder that this file is contained in. In all cases Windows will ask for the password again.

Also Windows remembers password only for some time, definitely if you reboot Windows then it will forget and ask password again.

I tried reproducing your problem on my Windows and it acted totally same on my machine, I created archive with your Python code and then `Extract files` didn't ask for password on second try.

Comment: @Rishi If my answer was correct and/or useful don't forget to Accept and/or UpVote it. Accepting and UpVoting can be done at the top of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67342938/941531), to the left from top there is Check-Mark for Accepting and Upper-Arrow for UpVoting.

Comment: Accepted your answer but not able to upvote 'cause I'm not having enough reputation.

Comment: @Rishi Thanks for accepting. BTW, you'll be able to upvote at reputation 15 or maybe 20. Now you have 13.